# How to group and filter top from each group

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to group a dataset with around 60 row to just have the top 3 by raceId, I have also tried to plot it but I no way works

```
raceId  driverId   milliseconds position
1061    830      1538426    1
1061    1        1539856    2
1061    822      1545928    3
1065    822      1674078    1
1065    830      1676403    2
1065    817      1688612    3
1071    822      1749559    1
1071    830      1750729    2
1071    832      1768282    3
```

This is practically what I would like to have so I can make a bar plot by raceId with just the top 3 and the times.

I'm new to all of this.... sorry if it's not clear or dumm

```
df_top_positions=df.groupby("raceId","driverId","milliseconds"), ['position'].min(3)
```

Comment: If you want to have top 3 row by raceId, just sort it according to raceId column and then get the first 3, you don't do group unless you want to do some aggregation.

Comment: `df.sort_values(by=['raceId'], ascending=False).head(3)` should give you what you are looking for.